# Unicorn restart/upgrade doesn't work

Tags: unicorn

Following is link to my init script for unicorn.
https://gist.github.com/1466775

Restart command has never worked for me. I am using upgrade to restart unicorn after each deploy. But whenever there is major changes like new gems being added, upgrade won't work. Recently, i replaced hoptoad gem with airbrake and it errors out saying 'uninitialized constant Airbrake (NameError)'. But when i stopped and started unicorn again, it worked fine. Does the problem lies in init script or its different problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

According to your init script, "/bin/init.d/unicorn restart" sends HUP signal to unicorn master process

------cropped

```
restart|reload)
    sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
    su - $USER -c "$CMD"
```

-----cropped

This is what HUP does to unicorn process :

reloads config file and gracefully restart all workers. If the “preload_app” directive is false (the default), then workers will also pick up any application code changes when restarted. If “preload_app” is true, then application code changes will have no effect.

What you are looking for is USR2 signal which your upgrade parameter to unicorn is already doing !

USR2 signal re-executes the running binary. A separate QUIT should be sent to the original process once the child is verified to be up and running.

Comment: While this is correct, we can't tell what your problem is without seeing the unicorn config. Basically, if it sets `preload_app` to true somewhere, you will need to use the "upgrade" command AND you will need to have extra code in your unicorn config to make it work. Google "unicorn zero downtime deploy" should bring up examples. If you **don't** set `preload_app`, your `restart` would be the correct option, but it will completely restart the server, causing it to be offline for a moment.

Answer (score 10):

I had a very similar problem and finally [found the solution](http://blog.willj.net/2011/08/02/fixing-the-gemfile-not-found-bundlergemfilenotfound-error/)

I had looked through the logs before but obviously failed to see the `(Bundler::GemfileNotFound)` error. Turns out there are old references to earlier releases and once the gem file changes, the new master silently fails. Tail -f your unicorn log to see what happens. My issues were all fixed as per the link with the following in my unicorn.rb

```
 before_exec do |server|
    ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{root}/Gemfile"
 end
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sosedoff/capistrano-unicorn/commit/c1e7a3f2794dd070367d0808ad102a6d20d39cf2) may be a slightly better solution.

Comment: @anjan Yes, nice find. I'm not using capistrano-unicorn gem at the moment but that would be a good fix for those that are.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but I was using rbenv which was installed on per user basis.
I used this [init script](https://github.com/railscasts/335-deploying-to-a-vps/blob/master/blog-nginx/config/unicorn_init.sh)

I figured out that since my rbenv installed on per user basis I need to slightly change this:

```
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
```

with this:

```
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
```

Hope it will help you!

P.S. or somebody else since it's an old question =)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing my unicorn init.d script from

```
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E staging"
```

to this:

```
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$APP_ROOT/Gemfile bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E staging"
```

Which seems to point to the new bundle gemfile on every new release.
Taking inspiration from [this merge request](https://github.com/sosedoff/capistrano-unicorn/commit/c1e7a3f2794dd070367d0808ad102a6d20d39cf2#diff-14f6e151876ce4733900b16e3c2e8ddb)